# Overlay modal using jquery hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do an overlay for my post content, like a 'full-screen modal dialog'. I've stuck at hiding and showing my content and items. I want when the content is shown, the items will become invisible.

http://jsfiddle.net/vjdwLzx8/

```
$(function(){
    $('.item').on('click',function(){
        $(this).next('.content').css('display','block');
    });


});
```

I also tried

```
 var item= $(this).next('.content').detach();
$('body').html('').append(item.css('display','block');
```

but I have to reload the page to get back to the item page which is something bad.

Comment: do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/vjdwLzx8/1/

Comment: Do you want to hide item and show corresponding content?

Comment: @dfsq yes, hide all the item and show clicked item's content

Comment: @jameslebron: didn't my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an overlay div

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

css:

```
.overlay {
    display:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 100;
    background: black;
}
```

onClick of items activate overlay and show content.

```
$(function () {
    $('.item').on('click', function () {
        $('.item, .content').hide();
        $('.overlay').show();
        $(this).next('.content').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close-content').on('click', function () {
        $('.content, .overlay').hide();
        $('.item').show();
    });

});
```

Also added provision for a close button.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjdwLzx8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

use

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/edu5yyrg/)

```
 $('.item').on('click',function(){
      $('.content').hide(); // hide 
        $(this).next('.content').show(); // show
    });
```

**WITH ANIMATION**

[**DEMO FIDDLE**(Animation)](http://jsfiddle.net/edu5yyrg/1/)

```
 $('.item').on('click', function () {
    $('.content').hide("slow", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    }); // hide 
    $(this).next('.content').show("slow", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    }); // show
});
```

Comment: @jameslebron: if my answer is your solution..please accept my answer